# Window-size-dependent navigation menu with animation effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Other people will be looking at this jquery code and i'm not an expert with jQuery so im asking. How can i make this jQuery code shorter, more efficient, and easier to read?

```
/* 
HEADER NAVIGATION 
*/
/* navigation tabs click highlight */
$(".header-main-tabs").click(function() {
$(".header-main-tabs").removeClass("header-tab-selected");
$(this).addClass("header-tab-selected");
});
/* drop menu hide and show for desktop */
$(".header-main-tabs").hover(function() {
$(this).children(".header-drop-menu").toggleClass("show-drop-menu-hover");
});

/* search input hide and show when search icon is pressed */
$("#search-icon-container span").click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass("fa-times");
$("#search-input-container").fadeToggle("fast");
});

/* mobile navigation */
/* show mobile tabs when toggle nav mobile button is clicked and when browser width is      over 990px */
/* toggle mobile navigation when nav button is clicked */
$("#toggle-mobile-nav").click(function() {
$("#nav-tabs-list").slideToggle();
$("#toggle-mobile-nav").toggleClass("toggle-mobile-nav-clicked");
});

var browserWidth = $(window).width();

$(window).resize(function() {
browserWidth = $(window).width();
if (browserWidth > 990) {
    $("#nav-tabs-list").show();
}
 });

$('#nav-tabs-list li').click(function() {
if (browserWidth <= 990) {
    $('#nav-tabs-list').slideUp();
}
});

/* always show drop menu when on mobile version (when browser width is below 960px) */
$(document).ready(function() { 
fadeMobile();  
});

$(window).resize(function() { 
  fadeMobile();  
});

function fadeMobile() {
  browserWidth = $(window).width(); 
  if (browserWidth < 990) { 
$("#nav-tabs-list").hide();
    $('.header-drop-menu').show(); 
    $("#toggle-mobile-nav").removeClass("toggle-mobile-nav-clicked");
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

### Easier to Read

Make sure you use the same standard everywhere, indent nicely and be consistent. Then the code already looks a lot better:

```
/* 
HEADER NAVIGATION 
*/

/* navigation tabs click highlight */
$(".header-main-tabs").click(function() {
    $(".header-main-tabs").removeClass("header-tab-selected");
    $(this).addClass("header-tab-selected");
});

/* drop menu hide and show for desktop */
$(".header-main-tabs").hover(function() {
    $(this).children(".header-drop-menu").toggleClass("show-drop-menu-hover");
});

/* search input hide and show when search icon is pressed */
$("#search-icon-container span").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-times");
    $("#search-input-container").fadeToggle("fast");
});

/* mobile navigation */
/* show mobile tabs when toggle nav mobile button is clicked and when browser width is      over 990px */
/* toggle mobile navigation when nav button is clicked */
$("#toggle-mobile-nav").click(function() {
    $("#nav-tabs-list").slideToggle();
    $("#toggle-mobile-nav").toggleClass("toggle-mobile-nav-clicked");
});

var browserWidth = $(window).width();

$(window).resize(function() {
    browserWidth = $(window).width();
    if (browserWidth > 990) {
        $("#nav-tabs-list").show();
    }
});

$('#nav-tabs-list li').click(function() {
    if (browserWidth <= 990) {
        $('#nav-tabs-list').slideUp();
    }
});

/* always show drop menu when on mobile version (when browser width is below 960px) */
$(document).ready(function() { 
    fadeMobile();  
});

$(window).resize(function() { 
    fadeMobile();  
});

function fadeMobile() {
    browserWidth = $(window).width(); 
    if (browserWidth < 990) { 
        $("#nav-tabs-list").hide();
        $('.header-drop-menu').show(); 
        $("#toggle-mobile-nav").removeClass("toggle-mobile-nav-clicked");
    }
}
```

### Shorter

- Don't use `$('...')` twice for the same selector and don't use it in an event. Instead, save the element in a variable and use that. It's both faster and easier to read
- Group events on the same element. The first 2 events are both placed on `$('.header-main-tabs')`, group them together
- Put all code in the `$(document).ready()` callback, this will avoid "DOM not ready" errors
- Use CSS to hide/show elements, don't use jQuery for that
- Combine the same events, you now have 2 `$(window).resize()` events
- Don't show on each resize, only show if it was hidden before
- Don't use global variables to store data

```
/* 
HEADER NAVIGATION 
*/

$(document).ready(function () {

    var $mainTabs = $(".header-main-tabs");
    var $searchInputContainer = $("#search-input-container");

    $mainTabs
        .click(function() { // navigation tabs click highlight
            $mainTabs.removeClass("header-tab-selected");

            $(this).addClass("header-tab-selected");
        }) 
        .hover(function() { // drop menu hide and show for desktop
            $(this).children(".header-drop-menu").toggleClass("show-drop-menu-hover");
        });

    /* search input hide and show when search icon is pressed */
    $("#search-icon-container span").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("fa-times");

        $searchInputContainer.fadeToggle("fast");
    });

    /* mobile navigation */
    /* show mobile tabs when toggle nav mobile button is clicked and when browser width is      over 990px */
    /* toggle mobile navigation when nav button is clicked */
    var $navTabsList = $("#nav-tabs-list");
    var $toggleMobileNav = $("#toggle-mobile-nav");
    var $headerDropMenu = $('.header-drop-menu');

    $toggleMobileNav.click(function() {
        $navTabsList.slideToggle();

        $toggleMobileNav.toggleClass("toggle-mobile-nav-clicked");
    });

    $(window).resize(function() {
        browserWidth = $(window).width();

        if (browserWidth > 990 && $navTabsList.is(':hidden')) {
            $navTabsList.show();
        }

        fadeMobile();
    });

    $('li', $navTabsList).click(function() {
        if ($(window).width() <= 990) {
            $navTabsList.slideUp();
        }
    });

    /* always show drop menu when on mobile version (when browser width is below 960px) */
    fadeMobile();  

    function fadeMobile(browserWidth) {
        if (browserWidth < 990) { 
            if ($navTabsList.is(':visible')) {
                $navTabsList.hide();
            }

            if ($headerDropMenu.is(':hidden')) {
                $headerDropMenu.show(); 
            }

            if ($toggleMobileNav.hasClass('toggle-mobile-nav-clicked')) {
                $toggleMobileNav.removeClass("toggle-mobile-nav-clicked");
            }
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

All changes are documented below, however here is a quick-hit list:

> - contain everything in $(document).ready() to ensure elements exist before assigning handlers
> - make better use of caching, `.find()`, and event delegation
> - combine width-specific functions into a single item, with width passed as parameter
> - make use of `.on()` rather than shorthand (`.click()`, `.hover()`) to combine bindings into a single handler
> - split `hover` into `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` to prevent possible double-toggling

Many of these not only make the code more readable, but makes runtime much faster by preventing excessive DOM querying, having smaller object sets to source from, consolidating similarly-applied code, and removal of unneeded code / event handlers.

Here's a draft of the new setup:

```
/* contain everything within a $(document).ready() function to ensure elements 
* exist before handlers assigned to them - shorthand of $(function used here */

$(function() {
    /* 
    * cache objects used more than once, as well as appropriate children
    * make use of $(this) rather than re-querying the DOM
    * make use of .find() selector when caching children rather than requerying for a new object
    */
    var $mainTabs = $(".header-main-tabs"),
        $headerDropMenu = $mainTabs.children('.header-drop-menu'),
        $navTabsList = $("#nav-tabs-list"),
        $searchInputContainer = $("#search-input-container"),
        $toggleMobileNav = $("#toggle-mobile-nav");

    /* place function declarations prior to event handlers in case any of the handlers use it,
    * and consolidate your winWidth-based logic into one function */
    function setMobile(winWidth) {      
        /* this was two separate functions, since you run this every time you can consolidate */
        if (winWidth <= 990) { 
            $navTabsList.hide();
            $headerDropMenu.show(); 
            $toggleMobileNav.removeClass("toggle-mobile-nav-clicked");

            /* only bind the click handler if winWidth calls for it, and use delegation of click 
            * events where possible, rather than using CSS selector */
            $navTabsList.on('click','li',function() {           
                $navTabsList.slideUp();
            });
        } else {
            $navTabsList.show();
            $headerDropMenu.hide(); 
            $toggleMobileNav.addClass("toggle-mobile-nav-clicked");

            /* else remove the binding */
            $navTabsList.off('click');
        }
    }

    /* combine multiple on declarations into a single .on() binding */
    $mainTabs.on({
        click:function(){
            $mainTabs.removeClass("header-tab-selected");
            $(this).addClass("header-tab-selected");
        },
        /* separate hover event into mouseenter / mouseleave to prevent possible double-toggling,
        * which can happen on rapid hover changes and .toggleClass() */
        mouseenter:function(){
            $headerDropMenu.addClass("show-drop-menu-hover");
        },
        mouseleave:function(){
            $headerDropMenu.removeClass("show-drop-menu-hover");
        }
    });

    $searchInputContainer.on('click','span',function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("fa-times");
            $searchInputContainer.fadeToggle("fast");
    });

    $toggleMobileNav.on('click',function() {
        $navTabsList.slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass("toggle-mobile-nav-clicked");
    });

    /* call your consolidated function, passing the width as parameter rather then
    * assigning to a variable within the function */
    setMobile($(window).width()); 

    /* change to non-shorthand in case you wanted to add a different window 
    * handler later ('load' to wait for images, for example). also, contain it within the 
    * document.ready so that it doesnt accidentally fire before document.ready (bug in early 
    * webkit versions) */
    $(window).on('resize',function() {
        setMobile($(window).width());
    });
});
```

Here it is without the clutter of the comments:

```
$(function() {
    var $mainTabs = $(".header-main-tabs"),
        $headerDropMenu = $mainTabs.children('.header-drop-menu'),
        $navTabsList = $("#nav-tabs-list"),
        $searchInputContainer = $("#search-input-container"),
        $toggleMobileNav = $("#toggle-mobile-nav");

    function setMobile(winWidth) {      
        if (winWidth <= 990) { 
            $navTabsList.hide();
            $headerDropMenu.show(); 
            $toggleMobileNav.removeClass("toggle-mobile-nav-clicked");

            $navTabsList.on('click','li',function() {           
                $navTabsList.slideUp();
            });
        } else {
            $navTabsList.show();
            $headerDropMenu.hide(); 
            $toggleMobileNav.addClass("toggle-mobile-nav-clicked");

            $navTabsList.off('click');
        }
    }

    $mainTabs.on({
        click:function(){
            $mainTabs.removeClass("header-tab-selected");
            $(this).addClass("header-tab-selected");
        },
        mouseenter:function(){
            $headerDropMenu.addClass("show-drop-menu-hover");
        },
        mouseleave:function(){
            $headerDropMenu.removeClass("show-drop-menu-hover");
        }
    });

    $searchInputContainer.on('click','span',function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("fa-times");
            $searchInputContainer.fadeToggle("fast");
    });

    $toggleMobileNav.on('click',function() {
        $navTabsList.slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass("toggle-mobile-nav-clicked");
    });

    setMobile($(window).width()); 

    $(window).on('resize',function() {
        setMobile($(window).width());
    });
});
```